# oracle merge statement when entire row not matched

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables in oracle. 
One contains 600000 rows and other staging table contains more than 600000 rows. 
I want to insert from staging table to actual table if any new rows available in staging table using merge statement. (or any other better way is there?)
(both table is in same structure and around 15 columns and instead of checking one single primary key I want to check all fields for matching condition).

Anybody can help please..

Comment: merge seems like the way to go

Comment: hi  Thank you...can you please help me  with one example that is checking multiple fields

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use the MERGE as per normal:

```
MERGE INTO bonuses b
 USING (
   SELECT employee_id, salary, dept_no
   FROM employee
   WHERE dept_no =20) e
ON  (b.employee_id = e.employee_id
 AND b.dept_no = e.dept_no)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET b.bonus = e.salary * 0.1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (b.employee_id, b.bonus)
   VALUES (e.employee_id, e.salary * 0.05)
   WHERE (e.salary > 40000);
```

But in the "ON" clause just join all the columns you want.

Using MERGE is definitely the way to go.